# Aborted connection 3 to db: 'default_schema' user: 'root' host: 'X.X.X.X' (Got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am running Django in a docker container and also I have MYSQL container running as well when I try to make a GET request I get the following from the logs. I have tried to add `--max_allowed_packet=1073741824` in my docker-compose file  but I still get the same error.

```
.....
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7

    command: --max_allowed_packets=1073741824

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
      MYSQL_DATABASE: default_schema
      MYSQL_USER: ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
.....
```

**Logs**

```
    Aborted connection 3 to db: 'default_schema' user: 'root' host: 'X.X.0.X' (Got an error reading communication packets)

 How do i fix it?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aborted clients usually occured when connected to db but closed db improperly, such as:

1. forget to close connection
2. idle duration great than `wait_timeout` or `interactive_timeout`
3. During the transmission of data, client shut down the connection
4. clients received data length great than `max_allowed_packet`, and that your clients are not receiving a “packet too large” message

[this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/) maybe help!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented pagination in the backend server and this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding docker specifically, this may be of help:

> First of all please change the root pw in the docker-compose yaml. Then try to create the volumes in another directory, for example /opt/monicahq or something like that. Docker can have problems with permissions in user based directorys.

https://github.com/monicahq/monica/issues/2989